# How get the Firebase Build Time every time I deploy my site?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to collect the build time/ deploy time when I deploy my site using the firebase hosting platform. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Sharing the code will be really helpful. My project is based on React + Vite and it used Firebase authentication. I deployed my project on Firebase.

I used this code on firebase.json

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Build-Time",
        "value": "$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and called a fetchData function inside a useEffect with empty dependency array on the App.jsx component of my React project:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://simple-login-de1a6.web.app/');
        const buildTime = response.headers.get('Build-Time');
        console.log('Build Time:', buildTime);
        // Use the buildTime value in your project as needed
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

It is not working. If I run my client side, the console tab on Google shows no result although I consoled the buildTime. Am I doing it correctly? I need the build time every time I deploy the website after updating any code.